# Os novos moderadores ficarão por quanto tempo no cargo?

Tags: debate, eleição

Ao se candidatar e caso vença, os novos moderadores atuarão por um período determinado (creio eu). Por quanto tempo eles ficarão no cargo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O cargo é vitalício, mas os ocupantes podem desistir quando quiserem. Ou podem ser destituídos pela Stack Exchange, por terem cometido alguma falta grave no exercício da função, ou por desagradarem profundamente a comunidade que deveriam representar.

Referência oficial: [Quem são os moderadores do site e o que fazem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)